# How do I make links with no href attribute accessible?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, anchor, wai-aria

A third party script is being used on a site I work on that replaces a few instances of `<a href="">` with `<a>`. The links still work thanks to another part of the script, but they are no longer treated as links by user agents.

I can restore them to the tabbed navigation order by adding `tabindex="0"` but how can I make assistive technologies announce them as links or include them in a list of all links on a page?

Would adding `role="link"` help at all?

I am pushing the third party to improve their script so that the href is left intact. But in the meantime how do I best repair the damage that's being done?

I can't add either the original `href` or something like `href="#"` back to the links as the third party code will no longer do what it does. I hope that they improve their code so that I can, but for now I need to make the link accessible without the 'href'.

Comment: think you'll need to provide example of how the links get to work any way.... youl'll wan't to get the original href from where they store it for the js-action.

Comment: The code that the 3rd party is using to customise content and track links won't work if I add the href attribute back into the links. I have no control over this code, but to satisfy the curiosity of anyone who wants to see it: http://jsfiddle.net/eNjnu/

Comment: I wonder if you can name the 3rd party involved here? Or reveal more about how it handles the clicks on the links - are there other assumptions it makes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make a non-href `<a>` behave like an `<a>` (and be accessible), you'd have to add `role=link`, `tabindex=0`, style it to look like a real link, *and* add keyboard handler code to treat Return as a click.

`role="link"` isn't sufficient; a screenreader may report it as a link, but without `tabindex="0"` and appropriate visual styles, a sighted user won't be able to tab to it in the first place, and without a keyboard event handler, only mouse users will be able to click it. (Technically screenreader users typically have hotkeys to simulate a mouse click, but keyboard-only sighted users generally don't have that option, so don't rely on it.)

Alternatively, if (big if!) the crazy script you're using allows for it, you could try shimming a 'keyboard click source' (my terminology) `<a>` just inside the original one: so where you have:

```
<a>foo</a>
```

you replace it with:

```
<a><a class='shim' href="javascript:void(0)">foo</a></a>
```

(The `class='shim'` is only needed if you need to do the event stuff described later...)
You can do this in jQuery using something like: (borrowing from Jack's answer)

```
$("a:not([href])").wrapInner("<a class='shim' href='javascript:void(0)'></a>")
```

How this works is that the inner newly-added `<a ...>` has a `href`, so it is exposed as a link and is tabbable. More importantly, if a user tabs to it and presses return, the default A behavior converts that keyboard input into a `click` event. This specific A has a `href` that returns undefined/void(0), so no actual navigation happens, but the click event will still bubble up to the original A, which gets to act on it.

(This is a neat pattern for allowing some parent element - often a DIV or similar - to handle click events, adding a child tabbable A that can source click events from keyboard gives you UI that's both mouse and keyboard usable.)

The big caveat here is that it assumes that your original script doesn't care about the `target` of the event. If that script does check this, it will get confused when it sees click events coming from the shim A's rather than the original As. One way to get around this is to capture and re-raise the event, which can be fiddly, and may only work on recent browsers - eg using something like:

```
// 'shim' class used so we can do this:
$("a.shim").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // the following works if listener using jQuery or is setting onclick directly, otherwise...
    // $(e.target).parent().click();.

    // More general way to raise events; may need alternate for IE<9
    var e2 = document.createEvent("UIEvents");
    e2.initUIEvent("click", true, true, window, 1);
    e.target.parentNode.dispatchEvent(e2)
});
```

Comment: Seems to work. I needed to wrap it in a timer as the 3rd party script makes it changes to the page in response to an ajax call that it initiates, but other than that it works just fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: Cool; glad it seems to work. Did you need to do any of the event stuff, or were the "event source" A links sufficient? Please do let the 3rd party know about their accessibility issue; keep in mind that while you know it's an issue and have a fix, others who use their code might not be as aware, so will end up with pages that are needlessly inaccessible without even realizing it. The code above is a workaround, not a fix.

Comment: The shim idea is a pretty neat idea but it uses invalid HTML.  An `<a>` is not allowed to contain a nested `<a>` (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element:concept-element-content-model), and if you need a clean WCAG report, it would fail 4.1.1. But still pretty cool.  My preference is to use what @BrendanMcK initially said with `role`, `tabindex`, and event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst it's not very pretty, you can get at all anchors without a `href` attribute like so, using jQuery;

```
$("a:not([href])")
```

You can then just set the `href` attribute on those links to "#" and that should make them work again as regular links.

[Here's a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EXRZK/)

Sorry to reply with a jQuery solution...but doing this in regular JavaScript would be much more verbose.

Another way would be to give the anchors a role and then select them that way:

```
$("a[role='link']")
```

Comment: Jack, adding href="#" breaks the links. If the code intercepted a standard click on the link then there wouldn't be a problem. But it doesn't, it relies on the fact that there is no href to do its thing. I hate badly written 3rd party JavaScript. :-(

Comment: Ah my apologies, I didn't realise. Is there an alternative script, or can you edit the original one? This script sounds like a major pain!