# NVDA reads href attribute when role="option" on Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, listbox, accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

I have a simple listbox

```
    <ul role="listbox">
        <li role="presentation" >
            <a role="option" href="javascript:void(0);" aria-selected="false">text1</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" >
            <a role="option" href="javascript:void(0);" aria-selected="true">text2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

But when I use NVDA on Internet Explorer, screen reader reads href attribute (for example "text1 javascript:void(0); not selected text1" or "text1 javascript:void(0); selected text2"). It occurs only on IE. Is there any way to use anchors in lisbox with NVDA and IE ?

Comment: What are you trying to do with anchors that buttons cannot do? Do you have an example URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making links with no href accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051353/making-links-with-no-href-accessible)