# How to make my click accessible through keyboard tab

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have this link that looks more like a button - but whenever I am testing my tab navigation via keyboard - this link is never it and the user can't use it.

How can I make it ADA compliant and use aria to make it accessible via keyboard?

```
<div class="styles">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="handlingClick($event)" id="addUser">Add User</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Without the href it won't be able to be focused; use a `button` instead.

Comment: @GregMcMullen - that worked!

Comment: @GregMcMullen this is why we have the "tabindex" attribute. The value "0" gives it a logical tab order based on its position in the DOM. No need to switch to a button.

Comment: @Nic -- My big thing, it's not a link, it's a part of the UI. Since it's not going anywhere and it's an interactive button it should be a button. But to each their own. I also don't like the idea of modifying the tab index without defining the entirety of the tab index. Just need to be careful of illogical tab index as a way of covering up HTML bad structure.

Comment: @GregMcMullen A tabindex with value 0 is the safe way of "including" an element to the tab index. This isn't some sort of hack, it's a basic HTML spec, and used widely to meet WCAG standards. Only values greater than 0 could create an illogical index.

Comment: @Nic Never meant to imply it as a hack. Multiple ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attribute.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="handlingClick($event)" id="addUser" tabindex="0">Add User</a>
```

The value `0` gives it a natural tab index based on the order of the DOM elements.

[Here is some additional documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H4.html).

Comment: is there any downfall to using tabindex everywhere? i feel like if i was to make an html change then i will have to make sure that the tabindex count is all up to date.

Comment: @bluePearl If you use the value 0 then it simply makes it focusable like it would be if it had the href attribute. You are not specifying an order -- the browser does this for you. So no, there is no downfall. This is how it's done. Check the additional documentation I just added to my answer for more info if you're interested.

Comment: when i tried this - i wasn't able to navigate or click (enter) the link when i used the tabindex = 0. it was getting focus but not working.

Comment: @bluePearl then your code only listens to the click event (enter =/= click). In which case a button might be more preferred after all.

Comment: You also need to add a role of link and add keyboard handlers, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12051353/557612

Answer (score 0):

Anchor elements are natively focusable. The reason that your link does not receive focus is because it doesn't have an `href` attribute.

Another way of approaching this problem would be to add a non-existent URL fragment identifier to the href attribute, like this:

```
<div class="styles">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#void" (click)="handlingClick($event)" id="addUser">Add User</a>
</div>
```